# Determine tetrahedron maximizing sum of edges over radius of circumsphere

Tags: geometry

Determine the tetrahedron $ABCD$ so that $\frac{L}{R}$ has the maximum value, where $L=AB+AC+AD+BC+BD+CD$, and $R$ is the radius of the circumsphere of $ABCD$.
sorry about my bad English ^-^

Comment: Can you find a formula for $R$ in terms of side lengths and angles?

Comment: It seems "obvious" that the tetrahedron you want is regular.  If so, formulas for the radius of the sphere are available on the web.

Comment: The regular tetrahedron has $L/R\doteq 9.8$, a flat square degenerate tetrahedron has $L/R\doteq9.65$.

Comment: @RossMillikan It is natural to think that the tetrahedron maximizing the given isoperimeter is probably regular. But do you have any clue how to prove it?